# How to deconstruct map to list?

Tags: kotlin

I have a List that contain country, I used groupBy to group them by country and now i would like to get fallowing result (for recycled view):

```
Country1
Airport1
Airport2
Airport3
Country2
Airport4
Airport5
Airport6
```

could someone give me a tip on how to do this?
My data class:

```
data class Airport(
val city: City,
val code: String,
val country: Country,
val name: String,
```

)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming:

- after you call `groupBy` you have a `Map<Country, List<Airport>>`
- you want the countries to be in alphabetical order
- you want to transform the map to a `List<String>`

This should do it:

```
airportsByCountry
    .toSortedMap()
    .flatMap { (country, airports) ->
        listOf(country.toString()) + airports.map { it.toString() }
    }
```